# start a node from another node just using launch file rather than lifecycle node in ros2

Tags: ros2

I am now using one node which just use camera to detect special symbols and then send cmd to chassis so that the car can run,also record the path for my car to navifate then.after notice the special symbol, I would like to shutdown the node before and start another node to navigate to
where the car start according to the path recorded before.

in order to finish this utility, i try to create a service and call it when catching a sight of the symbols, but i don't know how to send this request to launch files  to use event handlers,so i try another technique, set a parameter to tell if the car watch the symbols, but i also don not know how to monitor the changes of parameters in launch file.

i know that use lifecycle node can solve this question easily,but are there other techniques such as just using event handlers and substitutions in launch to finish this work?

appreciated it if anyone can come up with a new method or solve this question just based on my thought.

the os is ubuntu22.04 and ros2 version is humble